# Trying to count the number of times a cell is repeated excluding certain values using Python

Tags: python, pandas

Hi this is what I have currently, I am unable to provide he main document due to non disclosure purposes.

```
print (temo.head())

   Count 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
0      1   A1   TF   A2   B1   A3   A3             TF
1      1   A1   B1   A2   B2   A3   A4   A4   B3    
2      3   A1   A1   B1   A2   B2   A3   B3   B3   B3
```

I am trying to count the number of times a cell is repeated excluding the the value TF or any empty cells. For example, in the first row A3 is repeated once so the count would be 1. Again, in the third row A1 is repeated once and B3 is repeated twice so the count would be 3.

I tried using this, as suggested by someone.

```
temo.insert(0,'Count', temo.T.apply(pd.Series.duplicated).sum())
```

But it counts TF and empty cells as well

```
   Count 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
0      3   A1   TF   A2   B1   A3   A3             TF
1      1   A1   B1   A2   B2   A3   A4   A4   B3     
2      3   A1   A1   B1   A2   B2   A3   B3   B3   B3
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.mask((df=='')|(df=='TF')).T.apply(lambda x : x.dropna().duplicated()).sum()
Out[2023]: 
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @ScottBoston that is metioned by OP :-) Just help him fix that :-)